# syslog-ng startup failure when using /proc/kmsg

Tags: linux, syslog-ng

I have recently been updating `syslog-ng` from `3.7.3` to `3.13.2`. After the upgrade, the daemon fails to start with this error message:

> ```
> [2017-12-23T20:42:40.635915] Error checking the uniqueness of the persist names, please override it with persist-name option. Shutting down.; persist_name='affile_sd_curpos(/proc/kmsg)', location='/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:24:5'
> ```

For reference, line 24 of the config. See the whole file below.

> ```
>    file("/proc/kmsg");
> ```

I have been investigating this error for some time now, but the `persist-name` option does not solve the problem. The intended use does not seem to be related to this issue.

The configuration file I'm using is the default from hardened gentoo.

```
@version: 3.13
# Copyright 1999-2017 Gentoo Foundation
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2

# https://bugs.gentoo.org/426814
@include "scl.conf"

#
# Syslog-ng configuration file, compatible with default hardened installations.
#

options {
    threaded(yes);
    chain_hostnames(no);
    stats_freq(43200);
};

source src {
    system();
    internal();
};

source kernsrc {
    file("/proc/kmsg");
};

#source net { udp(); };
#log { source(net); destination(net_logs); };
#destination net_logs { file("/var/log/HOSTS/$HOST/$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.log"); };

destination authlog { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
destination _syslog { file("/var/log/syslog"); };
destination cron { file("/var/log/cron.log"); };
destination daemon { file("/var/log/daemon.log"); };
destination kern { file("/var/log/kern.log"); };
destination lpr { file("/var/log/lpr.log"); };
destination user { file("/var/log/user.log"); };
destination uucp { file("/var/log/uucp.log"); };
#destination ppp { file("/var/log/ppp.log"); };
destination mail { file("/var/log/mail.log"); };

destination avc { file("/var/log/avc.log"); };
destination audit { file("/var/log/audit.log"); };
destination pax { file("/var/log/pax.log"); };
destination grsec { file("/var/log/grsec.log"); };

destination mailinfo { file("/var/log/mail.info"); };
destination mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail.warn"); };
destination mailerr { file("/var/log/mail.err"); };

destination newscrit { file("/var/log/news/news.crit"); };
destination newserr { file("/var/log/news/news.err"); };
destination newsnotice { file("/var/log/news/news.notice"); };

destination debug { file("/var/log/debug"); };
destination messages { file("/var/log/messages"); };
destination console { usertty("root"); };
destination console_all { file("/dev/tty12"); };
#destination loghost { udp("loghost" port(999)); };

destination xconsole { pipe("/dev/xconsole"); };

filter f_auth { facility(auth); };
filter f_authpriv { facility(auth, authpriv); };
filter f_syslog { not facility(authpriv, mail); };
filter f_cron { facility(cron); };
filter f_daemon { facility(daemon); };
filter f_kern { facility(kern); };
filter f_lpr { facility(lpr); };
filter f_mail { facility(mail); };
filter f_user { facility(user); };
filter f_uucp { facility(uucp); };
#filter f_ppp { facility(ppp); };
filter f_news { facility(news); };
filter f_debug { not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail); };
filter f_messages { level(info..warn)
    and not facility(auth, authpriv, mail, news); };
filter f_emergency { level(emerg); };

filter f_info { level(info); };

filter f_notice { level(notice); };
filter f_warn { level(warn); };
filter f_crit { level(crit); };
filter f_err { level(err); };

filter f_avc { message(".*avc: .*"); };
filter f_audit { message("^(\\[.*\..*\] |)audit.*") and not message(".*avc: .*"); };
filter f_pax { message("^(\\[.*\..*\] |)PAX:.*"); };
filter f_grsec { message("^(\\[.*\..*\] |)grsec:.*"); };

log { source(src); filter(f_authpriv); destination(authlog); };
log { source(src); filter(f_syslog); destination(_syslog); };
log { source(src); filter(f_cron); destination(cron); };
log { source(src); filter(f_daemon); destination(daemon); };
log { source(kernsrc); filter(f_kern); destination(kern); destination(console_all); };
log { source(src); filter(f_lpr); destination(lpr); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); destination(mail); };
log { source(src); filter(f_user); destination(user); };
log { source(src); filter(f_uucp); destination(uucp); };
log { source(kernsrc); filter(f_pax); destination(pax); };
log { source(kernsrc); filter(f_grsec); destination(grsec); };
log { source(kernsrc); filter(f_audit); destination(audit); };
log { source(kernsrc); filter(f_avc); destination(avc); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_info); destination(mailinfo); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_warn); destination(mailwarn); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_err); destination(mailerr); };
log { source(src); filter(f_news); filter(f_crit); destination(newscrit); };
log { source(src); filter(f_news); filter(f_err); destination(newserr); };
log { source(src); filter(f_news); filter(f_notice); destination(newsnotice); };
log { source(src); filter(f_debug); destination(debug); };
log { source(src); filter(f_messages); destination(messages); };
log { source(src); filter(f_emergency); destination(console); };
#log { source(src); filter(f_ppp); destination(ppp); };
log { source(src); destination(console_all); };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not created by `syslog-ng` but by an apparmor profile. The profile prevents reading `/dev/kmsg`, which is needed even when using `/proc/kmsg` (which is whitelisted).

To see a full explanation and bug-report, check the answer I have written under a more specific question regarding this bug [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412724/252548).